# Switching to SE site doesn't perform login in certain situations

Tags: bug, notifications, login, openid

I usually login on the SE login site and go to the other communities from there. Usually, when switching the community by selecting it in the StackExchange Menu on the top left, I'm logged in after the community site has loaded.

However, when I got noe notifications or reputation changes from the same sites and click them, it takes me to the site they come from, but I'm not being logged in. Somehow this causes the notifications to maintain their *unread* status, so they're shown again on the next login.

Why does this happen and can it be fixed?